# Nested form child only updates if parent changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

[In this video](http://screencast.com/t/MDVhOWY5) (10 sec) you can see that the nested attribute is only updated if it's parent model is changed.

Using rails 3.0.0.beta and the [full project is on github](http://github.com/chap/broken_nested_attributes).

Summary of models and form:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :assignments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
end


form_for(@project) do |f|

  Project: f.text_field :name

  f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form|
    Task: task_form.text_field :name

    task_form.fields_for :assignments do |assignment_form|
      Assignment: assignment_form.text_field :name
    end
  end

  f.submit
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT2:** The same code works perfectly in Rails 2.3.5. It seems to be a bug in beta version.

**EDIT:** I wrote a test in my app to simulate this. Here's the result.

```
  test "should update empresa" do
    addr = empresas(:ufba).address
    put_with users(:s_one), :update, :id => empresas(:ufba).to_param,
             :empresa => { :address_attributes => {:id => empresas(:ufba).address.to_param,
                                                   :city => "Feira de Santana"}}
    assert_not_nil assigns(:empresa)
    assert_not_same addr, assigns(:empresa).address, "Endereco nao foi atualizado"
    assert_redirected_to empresa_path(assigns(:empresa))
  end
```

It runs without errors.

Comment: I've been testing in the console, and only works for Rails 2.3.5, on Rails 3.0 the Assignment is not updated.

Comment: Opened a ticket on the rails tracker and added failing unit test to demonstrate:
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/4242-nested-child-only-updates-if-parent-changes

Comment: I tried to find the code in Rails beta, still can't find where is the difference in the code that produces the error.